# How do I generate a random string as an movieclip? Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I am trying to create an animation of some random letters flowing like a stream.

I can get a random string for any letter that I want to appear as a trace statement, but I want them as a MovieClip on the stage so that I can add vectors to them

--Note
I am not able to do a textfield, because they all have to flow individually.

```
package{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class RiverOfLetters extends MovieClip{
        private var Letters:int = 25;
        private var numberofLetters:Number = new Number();
        private var LettersArray:Array = new Array();

        public function RiverOfLetters():void {
            numberofLetters = 300;  
            LettersArray.length = numberofLetters;
            // constructor code
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, oneachFrame);
        }

        public function oneachFrame(event:Event):void {
            for (var i:int; i < LettersArray.length; i++){
                trace (i);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have to go for separate **TextField** for each and every letter, exactly because you want to animate each individually. You can actually google a lot of examples, with **as3 flying text effect** like http://www.thewebsitedesigncenter.com/Flash-Effects.asp?FlashEffectID=111